# a very simple aop in spring 3 doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-aop

when i want to run a realy simple aop in spring 3 i get exception

```
start..
Aug 8, 2011 2:01:47 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@38c5c3ac: startup date [Mon Aug 08 02:01:47 GMT-12:00 2011]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 8, 2011 2:01:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [codes/aspect.xml]
Aug 8, 2011 2:01:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1089cc5e: defining beans [knifeBean,SingerBean,HeroBean,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,SingerPointCut]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 8, 2011 2:01:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1089cc5e: defining beans [knifeBean,SingerBean,HeroBean,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,SingerPointCut]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knifeBean' defined in class path resource [codes/aspect.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SingerPointCut' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SingerPointCut': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at codes.Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SingerPointCut' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SingerPointCut': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:820)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SingerPointCut' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SingerPointCut': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SingerPointCut': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
```

my codes=>>>

Hero.java:

```
package codes;

public class Hero {

    Knife knife;

    public Hero(Knife knife)
    {
        this.knife=knife;
    }
    public Knife getKnife() {
        return knife;
    }
}
```

Knife.java

```
package codes;

public class Knife {

    public void kill()
    {
        System.out.println("Killed!");
    }
}
```

Singer.java:

package codes;

```
public class Singer {

    public void beforeKill()
    {
        System.out.println("cha chah..before kill");
    }
    public void afterKill()
    {
        System.out.println("cha cha..after kill");
    }
}
```

aspect.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="knifeBean" class="codes.Knife"></bean>

<bean id="SingerBean" class="codes.Singer"></bean>

<bean id="HeroBean" class="codes.Hero">
<constructor-arg ref="knifeBean"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<aop:config>
<aop:aspect ref="SingerBean">
<aop:pointcut expression="execution(* *.kill(..))" id="SingerPointCut"/>
<aop:before method="beforeKill" pointcut-ref="SingerPointCut"/>
<aop:after method="afterKill" pointcut-ref="SingerPointCut"/>
</aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

test class:

```
package codes;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("start..");
        ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("codes/aspect.xml");
        System.out.println(ac);
        Hero sina=(Hero)ac.getBean("HeroBean");
        sina.getKnife().kill();
    }
}
```

and my jarfiles are:spring 3 jarfiles + common logging + aopppliance

i will be greatly thankfull for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack trace says you're missing `org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld` from your classpath.  This is found in the AspectJ JARs, either `aspectjweaver.jar` or `aspectjtools.jar`, depending on version.

Comment: why i should have them??i think a default aop ability comes from spring 3 pack.is not true?

Comment: i add aspectjweaver.jar and now i give new exception with this header:Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knifeBean' defined in class path resource [codes/aspect.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.

Comment: @sarah: So do what it says - add cglib to the classpath

Answer (score 13):

You are missing some dependencies.
If you are using maven add those dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Otherwise, just download the needed jars and add to your classpath.

Comment: But if that is a necessary dependency of Spring, why does Spring not declare it as a dependency?

Comment: I ran into this same error using Maven and placing the aspectjtools dependency fixed it. The cglib dependency was unnecessary as my project ran fine with it commented out.

Thank you, however, for the quick fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Cglib should be not needed if you expose interfaces for each pojo.